# Tailwind Grid, why are my elements rendering horizontally?

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

```
<div className='grid grid-cols-12 gap-12 mb-8'>
      <div className='col-span-8'>
        <div className='box'></div>
      </div>
      <div className='col-span-4'>
        <div className='box'></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Above is the HTML code that I am using along with the Tailwind CSS library, this is the output that I am getting.

[image: Output of HTML COde]
Shouldn't the elements render side by side, taking up the whole grid, as one has to take up 8 slots and the other one 4, which adds up to 12? I don't know why the elements are being rendered above the other.

The CSS class box is just:

```
.box{
  background-color: #2b2d40;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}
```

So finally my question is, how do I make it so that they are side by side in the same row, as that was the original output that I was expecting?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: seems to work fine without any change to your code https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzyCg.png

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas yeah even I just checked on the play.tailwindcss.com website and it seems to be working fine there. Can it be a project specific issue?

Comment: maybe yes, try using dev tools and see if there are some conflicts in CSS properties, and I saw also the jdawwgy answer and for me, if `col-span-8` doesn't work for you also him will not work, because the CSS is correct)

Comment: check if tailwind is downloaded correctly in your browser by using dev tools and click the div with `col-span-8` and should give you this https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7pn3.png, if not tailwind isn't configured or installed or something like that

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas yeah, I think my tailwind is not working properly, but it only seems to be the grid classes cause I can use the rest of the classes from tailwind fine. But, I am using the grid classes elsewhere in my project and it seems to be working fine there.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain on this topic. I find it to be much more reliable to use the `col-start-{n}` and `col-end-{n}` classes with tailwind grids. Try using these classes instead

```
<div className='grid grid-cols-12 gap-12 mb-8'>
    <div className='col-start-1 col-end-8'>
        <div className='box'></div>
    </div>
    <div className='col-start-8 col-end-13'>
        <div className='box'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `col-8`'s might have to be 9's I cant remember off the top of my head

Comment: Hmm unfortunately doesn't seem to be working

Comment: is your css compiling?

Comment: check if tailwind is downloaded correctly in your browser by using dev tools and click the div with `col-span-8` and should give you this https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7pn3.png, if not tailwind isn't configured or installed or something like that. your code is ok and fine

Comment: yeah, I think my tailwind is not working properly, but it only seems to be the grid classes cause I can use the rest of the classes from tailwind fine. But, I am using the grid classes elsewhere in my project and it seems to be working fine there.

Comment: if isn't working and you need to complete the working on the project, for now try to use the CDN (then you can focus on the setup/configuration problem) `<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>` (is always better to use NPM package, but for development porpuses also cdn is good, then you can always solve the tailwind integration then by just deleting the line of the `<script src="cdn....">` and use npm)

Comment: yeah its definitely a problem with the file, cause grid-cols-1 seems to be working as a class but anything above 1 is not working, and the CDN fixed it thanks :)

Comment: yes CDN is good, but if the project becomes more complex, is better to use NPM package instead so you can benefit from the speed and compilation process (for now development is good with cdn). an alternative solution is to do `npm install` and  `npm install -D tailwindcss` `npx tailwindcss init` just in case (maybe you forget it)